# There are 6 classifications of CFTR mutations. Is a causal relationship to the sweat test known?

Tags: genetics, dna, mutations

Cystic fibrosis (CF) is caused by mutations in the gene for the protein cystic fibrosis transmembrane conductance regulator (CFTR).

The CFTR mutations are classified in [6 classes](http://www.cftr.info/about-cf/role-of-ctfr-in-cf/cftr-mutations/the-six-classes-of-cftr-defects/).

The [sweat test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweat_test) is used to screen for CF. With the following boundaries:

- <= 29 mmol/L = CF is very unlikely
- 30 – 59 mmol/L = intermediate possibility
- => 60 mmol/L = CF is likely

Can I make assumptions from the sweat test in which category a patient may belong? Or can I even make assumptions about a specific mutation?

Comment: The results of the sweat test are due related to the total abundance of functional CFTR protein in the plasma membrane, so different classes of mutation that similarly reduce the total amount of functional CFTR would have similar sweat test results.